# Second form on page not performing any action

Tags: php, forms, submit

I have two forms on a page. The first is simply to allow the user to access blocked content. (I understand the risks associated with going this route, but it's just to allow members to view certain information that does not pose any sort of risks).

This is at the top of the page...

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] == 'password') {
        setcookie("password", 'password', strtotime('+1 day'));
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    }
?>
.....
<form method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="password">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-full" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

I believe this is preventing the second form (below) from operating (when you click the submit button, nothing happens. It's as if you hadn't hit the button at all).

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post" class="contactForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
         </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-full" />
    </div>
</form>
```

What can I do to fix the first part to allow the second form to function?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried it and it worked.

1) Make sure you have the handler.php file at the directory of index.php(according to your code).

2) Check for any console errors. If there is any then please attach it to your post.

3) and did you override the form submit event or input button press event from js?

Also I don't see anything where you are restricting the second form to appear when password is not set in cookie..
so better use:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['password'])): ?>

YOUR SECOND FORM

<?php endif; ?>
```

and hide the first form when password is entered.